# splitting a column in R and finding the mean

Tags: r, split

I have the following data frame(small subset from a big dataframe taken)

```
gene    counts  
a   1,4,5
b   2,1
c   9,2,4,5
d   1,2,3
```

I want to get the mean of column2 and then output it as the 3rd column. So I want some thing like this as my output:

```
gene    counts  avg
a   1,4,5   3.33
b   2,1 1.5
c   9,2,4,5 5
d   1,2,3   2
```

I tried something like this:

```
df <- read.table("test.txt",header=TRUE,sep="\t")
s <- strsplit(df$counts,split=",") # This creates a list with 4 elements in this case
```

This converts into character? Any help how can I get the average?

Thanks

Comment: what datatype is counts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
df$mean <- sapply(strsplit(df$counts, ','), function(x) mean(as.numeric(x)))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can loop through the `list` and get the mean

```
df$avg <- sapply(s, function(x) mean(as.numeric(x)))
df$avg
#[1] 3.333333 1.500000 5.000000 2.000000
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
   separate_rows(counts, sep = ",", convert = TRUE) %>%
   group_by(gene) %>%
   summarise(avg = mean(counts), counts = toString(counts))
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  gene    avg counts    
#  <chr> <dbl> <chr>     
#1 a      3.33 1, 4, 5   
#2 b      1.5  2, 1      
#3 c      5    9, 2, 4, 5
#4 d      2    1, 2, 3
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(gene = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), counts = c("1,4,5", 
"2,1", "9,2,4,5", "1,2,3")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -4L))

s <- strsplit(df$counts,split=",")
```

Answer (score 0):

### A lazy approach using eval and parse

```
sapply(paste0("mean(c(", df$counts, "))"), function(x) eval(parse(text=x)))
#   mean(c(1,4,5))     mean(c(2,1)) mean(c(9,2,4,5))   mean(c(1,2,3)) 
#    3.333333         1.500000         5.000000         2.000000
```

#### data

```
df <- read.table(text=
"gene    counts  
a   1,4,5
b   2,1
c   9,2,4,5
d   1,2,3",header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```